# Different between Caffe and Keras

Tags: caffe, keras, pycaffe, keras-layer

I have trained **LeNet** for MNIST using **Caffe** and now I would like to export this model to be used within **Keras**.

To this end I tried to extract weights from caffe.Net and use them to initialize Keras's network. However, I received different predictions from the two models. So I have tried to debug them layer by layer, starting with the first one. The code I have tested is as follows:

```py
# import caffe and load facce.Net from prototxt and caffemodel files
import sys
sys.path.append('/opt/caffe/python')
import caffe
net = caffe.Net('lenet_train_test.prototxt', 'save/mnist_iter_500000.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)

# this should be the kernel weights and bias for the first convolution layer 'conv1'
c1_w = net.params['conv1'][0].data
c1_b = net.params['conv1'][1].data

# import Keras and build a convolution layer using the same parameters as in lenet_train_test.prototxt and instantiate it with the weights above
import keras
from keras.layers import Convolution2D    
conv1 = Convolution2D(20, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(1, 28, 28), weights=[c1_w,c1_b], activation='linear')

from keras.models import Sequential
model=Sequential()
model.add(conv1)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])

# load MNIST data and do scaling like I did when training Caffe model
from keras.datasets import mnist
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_test *= 0.00392157

# set the first test example and get the prediction 
net.blobs['data'].data[0] = X_test[0][0]
net.forward()
out0 = net.blobs['conv1'].data[0] # this is the prediction for 20 kernels
m0 = out0[0]                      # just consider the first one
m0.shape  # >>> (24,24)

# pass the same example through the conv1 layer in Keras model
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros( (1,1,28,28) )
a[0] = X_test[0]
out1 = model.predict_on_batch(a)  # this is the prediction for 20 kernels

m1 = out1[0][0]                   # just consider the first one
m1.shape  # >>> (24,24) the same size

# I get a lots of 'False'
m0 == m1
```

Have I done anything wrong in the layer construction? or maybe Caffe and Keras implement the convolution2D differently?

Comment: OK. I've found the answer in https://github.com/MarcBS/keras/blob/master/keras/caffe/convert.py
>> caffe, unlike theano, does correlation not convolution. We need to flip the weights 180 deg

def rot90(W):
    for i in range(W.shape[0]):
        for j in range(W.shape[1]):
            W[i, j] = np.rot90(W[i, j], 2)
    return W

ThenConvolution2D(20, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(1, 28, 28), weights=[rot90(c1_w),c1_b], activation='linear')